# Grafana Influxdb show data cumulated for each month

Tags: influxdb

I have the data from my photovoltaik power for each day and each week. Where the week starts on Thursdays and ends on Wednesdays.

Now I would like to know how much I can produce in June, in July and so on.

But I do not know how to make this possible in Grafana.

```
SELECT sum(dtp) FROM (SELECT non_negative_difference("value") AS dtp FROM "mqtt_consumer" WHERE ("topic" = '$ahoyTopic/$ahoyInvertername/ch0/YieldTotal') AND $timeFilter) GROUP BY time(1w)
```

This is the query used to get the data for one week cumulated.

How can I say that I want it for each month, where the month indicates a calendar month e.g. to see the data for January, February etc without changing the query?

Comment: InfluxQL doesn't have concept of calendar month, so it is not possible without any workarounds, e.g. tag for month definition. Newer InfluxDB with Flux query language may be more suitable for this task.